# Wrong character translation for french language

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

i have a **textarea** field in which i am inserting text using jquery for french language
but unfortunetly, **é** is being displayed as `&#233;`.
I have made changes in the layout page

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

but it's still showing the data in wrong format

Comment: Can you share the code where you inserting text?

Comment: How do you get the text that gets inserted? If you're setting it in the back-end, you might need `Html.Raw`. You should post the relevant code.

Comment: jquery code : $("textarea#txtArea").text("é");

Comment: Try `$('textarea#txtArea').html("é");`.

Comment: It works now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a general solution for that since other characters could have the same issue, maybe in other languages.
Just make sure that the actual encoding of the textfile (I assume it'll be either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8) is in accordance with the meta tag defining the encoding in the beginning of the file. e.g.:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

For more info you could check [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)